# Objective C: when valueForKey is an instance with properties

Tags: objective-c

i am trying to extract a property of an instance of a class that is a property of another class! easier shown by example...

```
// Person is a class with properties: name and age
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
[person setName:@"Alex"];

// Age is a class with properties value (i.e. 100) and unit (i.e. year)
Age *age = [[Age alloc] init];
[age setValue:@100];
[person setAge:age];

NSMutableArray *people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[people addObject:person];

for (id person in people) {
```

how can i extract the value property of the age instance associated to the person?

```
    //[person valueForKey:@"age.value")];
```

i expect to get @100 - i get 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

this gives me the instance of Age - but i would rather have the value property.

```
    //[person valueForKey:@"age")];
}
```

is this possible? any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `valueForKeyPath:` rather than `valueForKey:` to handle [potential] traversal of an object graph rather than mere top-level look up.

`[person valueForKeyPath:"age.value"]` should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

you want to get `value` of `age` of `person`.
I changed the code to dot.notation, it's just `person.age.value`

```
 Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
  person.name = @"Alex";

  // Age is a class with properties value (i.e. 100) and unit (i.e. year)
  Age *age = [[Age alloc] init];
  age.value = @100;
  person.age = age;

  NSMutableArray *people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [people addObject:person];

  for (id person in people) {
    person.age.value
  }
```

Comment: thanks but i want to use valueForKeyPath so that i can dynamically retrieve *any* property