# Objective C: respondsToSelector when selector is associated to an instance's property

Tags: objective-c

this is a follow on question to [Objective C: when valueForKey is an instance with properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099767/objective-c-when-valueforkey-is-an-instance-with-properties). how do i check if an object responds to a selector that is attributed to one its properties?

```
// Person is a class with 2 properties: name and age
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
[person setName:@"Alex"];

// Age is a class with 2 properties: value (i.e. 100) and unit (i.e. year)
Age *age = [[Age alloc] init];
[age setValue:@100];

// set the age of a person
[person setAge:age];

// array to hold a bunch of "person"s
NSMutableArray *people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// add the person to it
[people addObject:person];

// a property that i want to dynamically test for
NSString *property = @"age.value";

for (id person in people) {
```

i can extract this property using

```
    NSLog(@"Property value: %@",[person valueForKeyPath:property)]);
```

but how can i check if the person class responds to it in some form or another?

```
    if ([person respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(property)]) {
        NSLog(@"Responds to selector: %@", property)

    }
}
```

the result of this boolean is NO but i require the syntax for YES. i.e. that its property, age, does responds to this selector, age.value.

any help is, as always, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how you've defined the relevant `Person` class and eliminate unnecessary details about the `Age` class?  Or wait... you're checking to see if `person` responds to `age.value`?  That's not going to work...

Comment: i am checking to see if `person` will/can respond to `age.value` in anyway? in a similar fashion that `valueForKeyPath:` works...

Comment: `age.value` is not a selector, it is a key path (that's why you're using it as an argument to `valueForKeyPath`...)

Comment: Don't use dynamism as a crutch. Rethink your goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string `"age.value"` is a key ***path***, not just a key. It's a compound string composed of two separate keys, `age` and `value`.

So, first, you can't use it with `-valueForKey:` because that takes a key, not a key path. There's a separate method, `-valueForKeyPath:` that takes a key path. Its default implementation basically breaks the key path into individual keys and uses `-valueForKey:` sequentially. That is:

```
[person valueForKeyPath:@"age.value"]
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
[[person valueForKey:@"age"] valueForKey:@"value"]
```

The `-respondsToSelector:` method checks if an object has a method whose selector is the same as the one you've passed in. That method can be the getter method associated with a property, but it's not testing directly for a property.

There's no method associated with a key *path*. There are only (potentially) methods for the individual keys of a key path. So, `NSSelectorFromString(@"age.value")` is not going to give you a meaningful selector, and no object is going to respond to such a selector even if it did (because selectors can't have dots in them).

You could write a method which will pick a key path apart into its component keys and test the successive objects. However, that will involve actually fetching the objects, because you can't ask the first object (i.e. `person` in your code) what some other object (i.e. an `Age` instance) responds to.

```
@interface NSObject (SupportsKeyPath)
- (BOOL) supportsKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath;
@end

@implementation NSObject (SupportsKeyPath)
- (BOOL) supportsKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
{
    NSString* key = keyPath;
    NSRange range = [keyPath rangeOfString:@"."];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
        keyPath = nil;
    else
    {
        key = [keyPath substringToIndex:range.location];
        keyPath = [keyPath substringFromIndex:range.location + 1];
    }
    BOOL result = [self respondsToSelector:NSStringFromSelector(key)];
    if (result && keyPath.length)
    {
        id next = [self valueForKey:key];
        result = [next supportsKeyPath:keyPath];
    }
    return result;
}
@end
```

Note how that has to call `-valueForKey:` to get the next object and then asks that object to evaluate the latter part of the key path. That request can have side effects. It's not ideal and not as "clean" as `-respondsToSelector:` because it **can't** be.